# Which Cache-control value will browser pick up

Tags: cache-control

In our Web app response headers i am seeing Cache-control values like this

```
     Cache-control : private
     xxxx
     Cache-control : no-cache, no-store
```

I am not clear on which value the browser will consider.  I think browser will take the first Cache-control value or will it consolidate all Cache-control values?
Even if it consolidate all Cache-control values then which one it will consider?
Can anyone help in making this point clear

Comment: Any update on this